# SQL statement to match dates that are the closest?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table, let's call it `Names`:

```
Name     Id    Date
Dirk     1     27-01-2015
Jan      2     31-01-2015
Thomas   3     21-02-2015
```

Next I have the another table called `Consumption`:

```
Id Date       Consumption
1  26-01-2015 30
1  01-01-2015 20
2  01-01-2015 10
2  05-05-2015 20
```

Now the problem is, that I think that doing this using SQL is the fastest, since the table contains about 1.5 million rows.

So the problem is as follows, I would like to match each Id from the `Names` table with the `Consumption` table provided that the difference between the `dates` are the lowest, so we have: `Dirk` consumes on `27-01-2015` about `30`. In case there are two dates that have the same "difference", I would like to calculate the average consumption on those two dates.

While I know how to join, I do not know how to code the difference part.

Thanks.

DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I believe that my question differs from the one mentioned in the comments, because it is much more complicated since it involves comparison of dates between two tables rather than having one date and comparing it with the rest of the dates in the table.

Comment: Which DBMS ? If it's mysql then above question would give you what you need. And if it is Sql server use the `Row_Number()`

Comment: I wouldn't call this duplicate. This is a more complex question. But a type of DBMS sure would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you could it in SQL Server:

```
SELECT Id, Name, AVG(Consumption)
FROM (
    SELECT n.Id, Name, Consumption, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY n.Id 
                        ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(d, n.[Date], c.[Date]))) AS rnk
    FROM Names AS n
    INNER JOIN Consumption AS c ON n.Id = c.Id ) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

Using `RANK` with `PARTITION BY n.Id` and `ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(d, n.[Date], c.[Date]))` you can locate all matching records per `Id`: all records with the smallest difference in days are going to have `rnk = 1`.

Then, using `AVG` in the outer query, you are calculating the average value of `Consumption` between all matching records.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1cf6f/1)